# Build size for LLVM 6.0.0 is huge (42G)

Tags: build, llvm

I built `llvm-6.0.0` from source and everything works fine. I'm just wondering how come its size is so huge (`42G`). Can I easily erase some object files or other to make the build directory smaller?

```
$ du -hs ~/GIT/llvm-6.0.0/build/
42G /home/oren/GIT/llvm-6.0.0/build/
```

Comment: You can do `make install` and then delete build and source directory altogether.

Comment: I actually need source files because I sometimes need to debug the llvm source code.

Comment: You still can delete build directory after installing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're building without shared libraries, which means that a number of very large libraries are linked statically into a large number of (otherwise small) tools. I'm guessing that you may also be building for all targets (32-bit ARM, 64-bit ARM, a few dozens more, 32-bit X86, 64-bit X86).

If you run `cmake -DLLVM_TARGETS_TO_BUILD=HOST -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RelWithDebInfo -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=on .`, you should reduce the space use to about 10G. (At least I have a 10G build tree produced from a similar command line. I also have bigger trees, because those settings aren't the best match for all purposes.)

Answer (score 0):

To anybody that is using `vcpkg` to build llvm.
You can pass `set(VCPKG_BUILD_TYPE release)` in the triplet that you use for example `x64-linux triplet`. This will prevent a buildtree of over 20GB and keep it under 10GB, was around 5GB when attempted, which you can delete and reclaim after installation is done.