# LLVM KaleidoscopeJIT: How to view errors?

Tags: c++, llvm, jit

I've been following the LLVM [tutorial](https://llvm.org/docs/tutorial/MyFirstLanguageFrontend/index.html) and I'm now trying to tweak & try extending things but I keep running into an error where code won't JIT & the compiler (the one I've made with LLVM) will abort with:

```
piler: /usr/lib/llvm-9/include/llvm/Support/Error.h:626: llvm::Expected<T>::storage_type* llvm::Expected<T>::getStorage() [with T = long unsigned int; llvm::Expected<T>::storage_type = long unsigned int]: Assertion `!HasError && "Cannot get value when an error exists!"' failed.
```

The assert is raised just after trying to get the address of the JIT-ted function:

```
 reinterpret_cast<double (*)()>(expr_symbol.getAddress().get());
```

I really need to see what the error is to attempt to fix it but I can't figure out how to get or view it.

Comment: Sounds as if you're using a release build of LLVM. You'll find development easier with debug symbols, e.g. [as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56018210/fnord) to a different question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this.

`.getAddress()` returns an [llvm::Expected](https://llvm.org/doxygen/classllvm_1_1Expected.html) which wraps around the address, it can contain an error or the address if found.

To handle/log the error you must 'take' the error and log it with `llvm::logAllUnhandledErrors`

```cpp
    auto address = expr_symbol.getAddress();
    if (auto err = address.takeError()) {
      llvm::logAllUnhandledErrors(std::move(err), llvm::errs(), "[JIT Error] ");
      return -1;
    }
```